# Multiple grounds from diode bridge? Safe or really stupid/dangerous?

Tags: audio, ground, high-voltage, ground-loop

I am making a hybrid tube preamplifier (one vacuum tube and one op-amp).  Both use very different voltages - the tube is getting somewhere about ~150V DC  and the op-amp gets ~6V  DC.  The differences are huge.

Can I connect the ground from 150v DC to  the ground of 6V DC?   Both are 'made' from a transformer and a diode bridge, filtered with capacitors.  I assume they both *should* be at 0V.  Based on that it seems to me that it should be *somewhat* safe.

Am I wrong?  Can it be done?  And can it be safe?  Or is it really stupid and should never be even considered?   I am just wondering, didn't actually try it - now I am asking.

[image]

*First stage of the preamplifier:    (~  150V   DC)
[image]

Second stage of the preamplifier:    (6v  DC)

[image]

Comment: Please provide a schematic of your input sides. It may be a case of business as usual or very dangerous depending on what you mean.

Comment: Good! Are they comming from two separate transformer or two windings from the same transformer? In the later case, are they connected in any way?

Comment: If the two AC inputs are isolated, and the two DC sides are currently not connected to each other in any other way, then it should be fine, and a reasonable thing to do.

Comment: Also there is no such thing as "at 0V". 0V is wherever you say it is.

Comment: One is direct from the outlet (220V AC)  but I 'named' it as 150V DC, as it later is dropped by a resistor to the tube... Let's say that it's 150V DC for now..  It goes through a diode bridge and is filtered by ~300uF to the ground.


The other is coming from a transformer.  Goes through a diode bridge and is filtered by 1000uF capacitor. 

Basically, they come from different sources (different transfomers)

Comment: Please explain "One is direct from the outlet (220V AC)". Are you not running it though a transformer?

Comment: No, I am not running it through a transformer.  I run 220v AC to the diode bridge and then filter it with capacitors.  I get ~220v DC which goes through a resistor to the anode of the vacuum tube.
Is this wrong that I am not using a transformer?

Comment: I think you need to edit that information into your question.

Comment: A transformer is an electrical device consisting of two or more sets of windings wound around an iron core. It is used to *transform* the voltage (more windings on one side means a higher voltage on that side, fewer windings means a lower voltage on that side). See this wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformer . You do not show a transformer, only a rectifier and a capacitor. Are we to assume you have a transformer with two secondary windings, one for 106VAC and one for 4.2VAC (which rectify to 150VDC and 6VDC respectively)?

Comment: The transformer is also part of the circuit ! It should have been included in the first schematic. Then it would be clear that the two AC inputs are isolated and that you **can** connect the grounds together.

Comment: The bridge rectifier alone will not succeed in isolating the ground of your 150V supply from the incoming supply voltage.  Without a transformer, your circuit is highly dangerous whether you connect the high voltage and low voltage grounds together or not.  Anyone touching the shield of the amplifier's input would be in danger of a mains-voltage shock.  The advice is sound: don't mess with mains voltages unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: In addition, you need to know that rectifiying an AC input of 220V RMS will not give you 220V DC, but more like 300V DC, because the capacitor will charge up to the peak input voltage. This is expained in any good electronics textbook.

Comment: @Giedrius You **MUST** use two transformers. Running 220VAC directly to a diode bridge is not legal and may kill you, or the user of the equipment.

Comment: @EJP Erm, how is rectifying mains illegal? Most cheap SMPS's do exactly that - rectify mains directly to DC, then chop that at a much higher frequency through a small transformer.

Comment: I was working these past days in variuos events so I couldn't give a quick response. I give a BIG thanks for all your support as once again - you helped me to solve the problem and to learn once more. Big big thanks to everyone!   :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can do that, even need to do that **if** each of the AC feeds in your schematic come from separate transformer windings.  Put another way, the two AC feeds must be floating with respect to each other.

With the AC feeds floating, the DC voltages derived from them will also float.  If you want the circuitry powered by one to drive a signal to the other, you also need to connect one other point between the two sections that will be the reference voltage for this signal.  The negative of the DC supply is a obvious choice, and it simplifies thinking about the circuit if you consider that to be the ground for both sections.

Comment: Olin, your answer assumes the questioner has both power supplied isolated from incoming mains voltage by transformers.  His comments indicate that this is not the plan.  As I commented above, even the 150V supply on its own is dangerous without this isolation.

Comment: @Mike: First, I clearly said both AC feeds need to isolated.  Second, that's exactly what they are.  See paragraph 2 sentence 2 of the question: *"Both are 'made' from a transformer and a diode bridge"*.

Comment: I'm sorry if what I wrote came across as critical of you.  That wasn't what I intended.  I felt a bit scared the OP was about to kill himself, since his comments below the question indicated that what you or I might mean be isolated by a transformer (in the appliance) is not what the OP meant: he is imagining the power company's transformer will do the business for him.  Sorry again for the offense.

Comment: @Mike: If he meant the power company transformer, then that's bad.  If this is really true, then he should add that to the question.  Pertinent information should never be hidden in comments.  No, I'm not going to read a lengthy comment chain.

Comment: Olin, this was not the first question/problem you helped me to solve. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you aren't regarding the whole circuit as potentially at mains voltage wrt ground and appropriately protected, then you need two isolating transformers, as noted.

This reminds me of old valve televisions which often had a hot chassis. They were (very nominally) safe because the entire system (including the speakers) was inside an insulated enclosure (having said that, there were numerous accidents where somebody managed to contact the chassis regardless). I doubt they'd be to code today.